# Aws Lex Speech to text shell commands

Tags: python, shell, amazon-web-services

```
 aws lex-runtime post-content 
--region eu-west-1 
--endpoint https://runtime.lex.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 
--bot-name TestingAutomation 
--bot-alias Automation 
--user-id 201448458653 
--content-type "audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1" 
--input-stream ogg.wav 
ConfirmOutputSpeech.mp3
```

**I tried this shell command but i did not get exact text file**

```
I get this output 
*{
    "message": "Sorry, can you please repeat that?",
    "inputTranscript": "",
    "dialogState": "ElicitIntent",
    "contentType": "audio/mpeg"
}*
```

please help me

Thanks

Comment: I am not an audio programming person, but is an argument like `--input-stream ogg.wav` consistent with a filename like `ConfirmOutputSpeech.mp3`? (From my limited knowledge, I would think you want a `--input-stream mp3` (or as appropriate)). ALSO, what is in `ConfirmOutputSpeech.mp3?  Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shelter, Thank you for ur comment, I tried input all audio input formats and output formats only i get this json sir